# GHPRB: Is it possible to stop Downstream Jobs when Pull Request is updated if downstream job is NOT using GHPRB?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have one high level controller task that I call "Manager". The Manager handles launching multiple downstream jobs using Github Pull Request Builder (GHPRB). Only the Manager uses that plugin.

All of the Downstream jobs use the option:

```
Set GitHub commit status with custom context and message (Must configure upstream job using GHPRB trigger)
```

What I have run into is the case where a developer opens a pull request (PR) and after that notices they want to make a change so they push a second commit before the downstream tests have finished.

The manager is easy to stop in this case as GHPRB provides a built-in feature in the "Trigger Setup". The feature is "Cancel Build on Update".

The issue I would like to solve is how to also kill the downstream jobs.

You can already stop jobs in Jenkins if two copies of the same job are running. What I am trying to figure out is:

If I have three copies of downstream "job A" running and all three are testing separate pull requests, that is great! If however two of those jobs are testing the same PR:

A. Can I detect that they are both testing the same PR?

B. If two tests are running on the same PR can I stop the oldest job in favor of the most recent job?

C. If A and B are possible which Jenkins plugin provides this solution?

D. If A and B and not C, how do I do this with existing functionality?

Comment: If there is some other solution to this problem aside from using environment variables please don't hesitate to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible with some other plugin or existing Jenkins functionality to check; If there are two tests and both have the same sha1 environment variable, stop the first test and build the newest test instead?

If your build is not one giant step, but a series of step, you might consider doing a `git fetch` between each step of your job.
If you job is configured for pull request branches ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39650017/6309)), using refspecs like `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`, you could chek if the branch `pull/aPullRequestID` HEAD has changed compared to `${sha1}`

Comment: Perhaps the question was unclear. It is not a question of which variables to compare. The question is "Does the functionality exist either in a Jenkins plugin or somewhere in Jenkins itself by which to do such a comparison". IE  "Is it possible to stop one test in favor of another test based on environment variables". You can already stop tests in favor of others in Jenkins but the conditions are on test names. If I have three copies of downstream job1 running and all three are related to separate PR's I don't want any of them to be stopped. If however two of them are for the same PR ...

Comment: It is clearer, yes. However, I don't know if a Jenkins feature or plugin which would provide that.